# Особенности работы с байтами

Tags: c

Имеется следующий код:

```
void *words;
words = (uint *)malloc(sizeof(uint)*2);

uint *t = (uint *)words;
*t++ = 4261142941;
*t = 1;
```

Я ожидал, что байты будут записаны в таком порядке:

```
4261142941 = 11111101 11111011 11100001 10011101
1          = 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

или обратном:

```
4261142941 = 10011101 11100001 11111011 11111101
1          = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

Но когда я начал считывать каждый байт:

```
for( uchar* i = (uchar *)words; i < (uchar *)(t+1); i++ )
{
    printf("%p -- %d \n",i,*i);
}
```

я получаю следующий набор байтов:

```
10011101 11100001 11111011 11111101 // т.е. обратный
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 // а тут прямой
```

Может кто-нибудь рассказать почему именно такой порядок ?

Comment: правильнее сказать почему вы в прямом порядке ждёте 1 такую? `11111101111110111110000110011101` - прямой и 1 - `00..001`. Оно и есть.

Comment: А покажите-ка код, которым вы получаете ваш результат? Полный компилируемый пример.

Answer (score 3):

Ожидания в вопросе неверны, например [от старшего к младшему (big-endian) порядок байт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) должен быть такой:

```
11111101 11111011 11100001 10011101
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

то есть единица с другой стороны в отличии варианта в вопросе (младший байт идёт последним). Вы получаете верный порядок от младшего к старшему (little-endian, "обратный"):

```
10011101 11100001 11111011 11111101
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

самый младший байт сперва идёт.

Проще в шестнадцатеричной системе на такие вещи смотреть (на Питоне):

```py
>>> 0xdeadbeaf .to_bytes(4, 'big').hex()
'deadbeaf'
>>> 0xdeadbeaf .to_bytes(4, 'little').hex()
'afbeadde'
>>> 1 .to_bytes(4, 'big').hex()
'00000001'
>>> 1 .to_bytes(4, 'little').hex()
'01000000'
```

In C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned a[] = {0xcafebabe, 1};
  unsigned *pa = a;
  for ( ; pa != &a[sizeof a / sizeof *a]; ++pa) {
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*) pa;
    unsigned char *pend = ((unsigned char*) pa) + sizeof *pa;
    printf("0x%0*x == ", 2 * (int)sizeof *pa, *pa);
    for ( ; p != pend; ++p)
      printf("%02x ", *p);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Пример:

```sh
$ gcc *.c -o show-byte-order && ./show-byte-order
0xcafebabe == be ba fe ca
0x00000001 == 01 00 00 00
```

Answer (score 2):

10011101 0-байт
11100001 1-байт
11111011 2-байт
11111101 3-байт

00000001 0-байт

Всё на своих местах. Было смешанное представление в ожидаемых вариантах: одно число big-endian, другое small-endian.